# How to find minimum value in an array using ternary operator in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
let array = [2,3,5,7,3,1,8,9,0,2,4,1]
var minvalue = array[0]
for values in array {
  values < minvalue ? minvalue = values : minvalue
}
print(minvalue)
```

This is the code i tried , I want the minimum value in the array, If I use `if..else` I can able to do but cant find using ternary operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ternary operator` this way.

```
for values in array {
    minvalue = values < minvalue ? values : minvalue
}
```

But in `Swift` instead of that simplest option is to use [`min()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1687893-min).

```
print(array.min())
```

Answer (score 0):

To Get **Min value** SWIFT 3

```
array.min()
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how to find through looping and ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sorting the array:

```
let sortedArray = array.sorted()
var minvalue = sortedArray[0]
```

Comment: Technically correct, but inefficient way to solve the problem.

Comment: why? would you please inform me?

Comment: Sorts find not only the smallest value, but also determine the second smallest value, the third smallest, etc. It's a lot more work than is required if you only need to know what the minimum value was. Even good sort algorithms are, say, O(n log n) complexity. The `min` function is a trivial scan through the results, with O(n) time and O(1) memory.